# Autorun Firefox on startup...grrrrrrr!

Tags: boot, script, lxde, sudo, lxsession

Long Story (Short):
Okay, I've read all of the guides, questions etc I can find and it's still not happening. I can't get the browser to open its self up when the pi boots.

Background:
I'm following this guide:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Wall-Mounted-Google-Calendar/?ALLSTEPS

To create a live calendar for my school staffroom. I've followed it to the letter but can't get the browser to open its self up when the pi boots.

So far:

1. I tried editing ***sudo nano /ect/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart***

   - I added ***@iceasel***  -  it didn't work
   - I took ***@iceasel*** out and put ***@firefox*** in  -  it didn't work
   - I changed ***@firefox*** to ***@firefox-esr***  -  it didn't work.
   - I tried all of the above with **-e** (as i thought this might mean execute?) - it didn't work.
2. I then found out that in the new Noobs build the file was called ***sudo nano /ect/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart***

   - So I did all of the above again to no great success :-(

I'm getting really frustrated with it. I have **very** limited knowledge with this kind of thing. I'm a problem solver who works extremly well on a software level but any coding and I'm in trouble -

Please help:
So that you don't get frustrated with me, I'm going to explain how to help me (I know strange approach right?)

Okay, if you are asking me to use any code etc please explain along side it in plain English where possible so I will know for future eg:

use sudo nano to open the file /ect/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
*sudo nano opens the text editor so you can edit the auto start config file*

OR

add **@firefox-esr - e** to the bottom.
*-e tells it to execute the file.* - is this correct btw?

Thanks in advance!

***EDIT:***
I started to use epiphany browser to make things simple and then logged into the google calendar I needed to open. In the file menu it gives the option to save as a web application. I did this now have ***calendar.google.com*** as an app. so, could I use ***@calendar.google.com*** to auto launch this app?

Comment: you keep mentioning `@iceasel` shouldn't it be `@iceweasel` ?? 
also can you do `cat /etc/debian_version` so that I can figure out which Version are you working on? We can find a solution don't worry

Comment: *"I'm a problem solver who works extremly well on a software level but any coding and I'm in trouble"* -> Don't think of it as coding (it isn't), think of it as  configuration sans checkboxes and menus.  BTW you'll find lots of LXDE related documentation [via their site](http://lxde.org/).  The "DE" stands for [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment#Desktop_environments_for_the_X_Window_System), which is a heterogeneous bag on GNU/Linux systems such as Raspbian.

Comment: wow, thanks guys I wasn't really expecting a reply as I know some forums do an *eye roll* at noobs like me. I'll act on these and post back. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked, thanks to all who had input (eps Shan-Desai)

Okay what I did:

***1)*** Fresh install of Noobs (Raspbian Jessie)

***2)*** sudo apt-get update.

***3)*** sudo apt-get upgrade.

***4)*** sudo apt-get install firefox-esr

***5)*** Then I tried to follow Shan-Desai's advice above with:

create a folder called 'lxsession' in your hidden folder called .config:

$ mkdir /home/pi/.config/lxsession

***BUT:*** *It said the directory already existed.*

***6)*** Used file manager to navigate to /home/pi/.config/lxsession

***7)*** Opened the AUTOSTART file and added ***@firefox-esr*** above the ***@screensaver*** line(can't remember the other part - something about splash?)

***8)*** sudo reboot

***9)*** It opened the browser on boot!

***10)*** I then logged in to the google calendar, saving my login details and used ***sudo reboot*** while it was still open. It opened the browser and auto logged in on reboot :-)

Hope this helps others and thanks to those who had input!

Comment: You can use `mkdir -p /home/pi/.config/lxsession`, it will not complain and create the directory if a component of the path is missing.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I am giving a shot at this, try following the mentioned steps (type in your Terminal):

1. create a folder called 'lxsession' in your hidden folder called `.config`:

   ```
   $ mkdir /home/pi/.config/lxsession
   ```
2. Depending on your Raspberry Pi Version you can try :

   ```
   $ mkdir /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/
   ```

   **OR**

   ```
   $ mkdir /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE/
   ```
3. now create a file called `autostart` in your above mentioned folder:

   ```
   $ nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
   ```
4. Autostart your application by typing the following in your above mentioned file:

   ```
    @iceweasel
   ```
5. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (this is the letter O) press **Enter** and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
6. You should reboot your Raspberry Pi using the following command in terminal:

   ```
   $ sudo reboot
   ```

   Once it reboots you should be able to see your browser open!

#### Note

In order to see which version you are using do :

```
  cat /etc/os-release
```

if it says `Jessie` you should use `LXDE-pi` in Step **2** above if not use the other one.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this I'll give it a go and post findings

Comment: FANTASTIC! I don't know how it worked but it did! Just one thing: When I tried to create the dir it already existed so I used file manager to track to the location all the way to autostart. Once opened in the notepad equiv I added @firefox-esr and ctrl+O it asked to save so I did then closed and rebooted. Worked a charm. Cheers.

Comment: sure what is it? also can you approve this answer if this worked?

Comment: I've upped your answer but accepted the answer I've posted as I've included the bit about file manager - if this annoys you I can click accept on yours, I just thought the end answer with the extra info would help others? If you want to copy and paste and post my answer I'll click accept on your version?