# Autorun Firefox in fullscreen-mode on startup

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, home-automation

**Here is what I am trying to achieve:**

When I startup my Pi 3 I would like it to directly launch into Firefox in fullscreen-mode directly. Or more specifically - no edges like toolbars etc., just the webpage.

I´m going to use a screen to show my own calendar and health status. And the idea is not to have a mouse or keyboard connected.

Has anyone done this before?

I´m starting to work on my own solution, but if someone has already done this I would appreciate the help.

Comment: have you considered simply running the pi 24/7 as boot times are rather horrendous in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

I've done this with chromium, should be similar for firefox.

```
sudo nano start.py
```

Contents of new file:

```
import os
os.system("chromium-browser --kiosk http://localhost/")
```

Then edit bashrc

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Added to bottom of file:

DISPLAY=:0 python start.py &

Running

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Should test whether the new file works. Try replacing chromium-browser with firefox. If that doesn't work you could always use chromium.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this before [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51720/autorun-firefox-on-startup-grrrrrrr/51723#51723)

If you are using **Jessie** then there should already be an existing folder for **LX-Session**. The folder is the following:

```
/home/pi/.config/lxsession
```

if you are using an older version then you can create it using:

```
mkdir -p /home/pi/.config/lxsession
```

Now, you can create a file :

```
nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/autostart
```

add the tag in the file of your browser:

```
 @firefox-esr (@iceweasel) # whichever you are using
```

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

then reboot your Pi:

```
 sudo reboot
```

This should get your browser working on reboot of Pi.

#### Notes:

try installing the `firefox-esr` using:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr
```

Try finding `autostart` file in the `lxsession/` folder,

for some Pis it is in

```
  ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/
```

or

```
   ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/
```

To have FireFox perform a clean start up. Need to go to about:config and search for exit then toggle " browser.helperApps.deleteTempFileOnExit " to false on reboot FireFox will open clean.

Comment: This works quite well! Only one issue left. When the raspberry is shut down with Firefox running, it's a chance Firefox saves information about improper closure of the app. Which will result in an error message next time the pi starts up. I tried to fix this, but can't find the file were Firefox is saving this information...